# How to return counts in a lookback period, unique to multiple fields?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is a sample of the dataset I have (~10 TB)

```
+----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| id | date       | campaign | campaign_start | campaign_end |
+----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 1  | 2018-01-01 | 1        | 2018-01-01     | 2018-02-03   |
+----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 1  | 2018-02-01 | 2        | 2018-02-01     | 2018-02-03   |
+----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 1  | 2018-02-02 | 2        | 2018-02-01     | 2018-02-03   |
+----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 1  | 2018-02-03 | 2        | 2018-02-01     | 2018-02-03   |
+----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 2  | 2018-01-23 | 1        | 2018-01-01     | 2018-02-03   |
+----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
| 2  | 2018-02-03 | 2        | 2018-02-01     | 2018-02-03   |
+----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
```

I want to:

For every unique id + campaign:

1. Get the frequency of occurrences of an id within the period of that specific campaign
2. Get the frequency of occurrences of an id within a variable lookback period (say 3 months) before the start of the campaign. Say " >= campaign_start + 3 months "
3. Get the earliest (first) and latest (last) date in that window

What I would like the output to be is:

```
+----+----------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| id | campaign | campaign_frequency | total_lookback_frequency | campaign_start | campaign_end | first_date | last_date  |
+----+----------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1        | 1                  | 1                        | 2018-01-01     | 2018-02-03   | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-01 |
+----+----------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 2        | 3                  | 4                        | 2018-02-01     | 2018-02-03   | 2018-01-01 | 2018-02-03 |
+----+----------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| 2  | 1        | 1                  | 1                        | 2018-01-01     | 2018-02-03   | 2018-01-23 | 2018-01-23 |
+----+----------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| 2  | 2        | 1                  | 2                        | 2018-02-01     | 2018-02-03   | 2018-01-23 | 2018-02-03 |
+----+----------+--------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

The problem I have been having is that I can't get the total_lookback_frequency to work properly, it always returns the same result as campaign_frequency (which is just a count(id) group by id, campaign.

Below is what I had (that isn't working):

```
SELECT  
  id,
  campaign,
  min(date) as first_date,
  max(date) as end_date,
  count(id) as total_lookback_frequency,
WHERE
  date >= sub(date, INTERVAL 730 hour)
GROUP BY
  id,
  campaign,
  date
```

Would you be able to help out here?

Thanks!

Comment: You should edit the question and show the query you have written.

Comment: Done! It's not the exact same as I missed out some joins.

Comment: are you sure you use BigQuery - please confirm!

Comment: Yes I am using BQ, cut out some of the BQ specific functions (for the date, for example. I'm actually using timestamp_sub)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  id,
  campaign,
  COUNT(1) campaign_frequency,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM `project.dataset.table` 
    WHERE id = t.id
    AND dt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(t.campaign_start, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(t.campaign_start, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ) total_lookback_frequency,
  campaign_start,
  campaign_end,
  MIN(dt) AS first_date,
  MAX(dt) AS end_date
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY id, campaign, campaign_start, campaign_end
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, DATE '2018-01-01' dt, 1 campaign, DATE '2018-01-01' campaign_start, DATE '2018-02-03' campaign_end UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-02-01', 2, '2018-02-01', '2018-02-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-02-02', 2, '2018-02-01', '2018-02-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-02-03', 2, '2018-02-01', '2018-02-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-01-23', 1, '2018-01-01', '2018-02-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-02-03', 2, '2018-02-01', '2018-02-03' 
)
SELECT 
  id,
  campaign,
  COUNT(1) campaign_frequency,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM `project.dataset.table` 
    WHERE id = t.id
    AND dt BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(t.campaign_start, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(t.campaign_start, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ) total_lookback_frequency,
  campaign_start,
  campaign_end,
  MIN(dt) AS first_date,
  MAX(dt) AS end_date
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY id, campaign, campaign_start, campaign_end
-- ORDER BY id, campaign
```

Comment: Hey! 

Thank you for your help, I'm running it now and will let you know once it's processed.

Comment: so, how it goes?

Comment: Currently been running for 13,000s... still running.
I'm guessing the count(1) applies row by row, so for a large dataset it's likely going to take a very, very long time?

Comment: i suspect your real query that you are running is quite different from one in answer. in any case 13,000s is enough to safely assume that something is not correct :o)